# Strange error phpMyAdmin\MariaDB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Today I decide to continue my work at project.

I need to rename field in table in phpMyAdmin. When I sent the following SQL query

```
ALTER TABLE `test_table`
    CHANGE `active_` `active` ENUM('Y','N')
        CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N';
```

I saw strange error of phpMyAdmin

> #1146

I copied it and pasted the sql statement here:

```
UPDATE `columns_priv` SET Column_name = "active"
    WHERE Db = "test"
      AND Table_name = "test_table"
      AND Column_name = "active_";
```

All OK, BUT, my database don't have table columns_priv.
The error vanished when I had clicked it.
The field was renamed as I wanted. But the error...
I repeat the action, the error is repeated too.

My privileges allow to me to work with one base only. However when I give to myself all privileges, I can see all databases, include "mysql" database  where the table "columns_priv" exists and then the error don't show.

Before, all was good.

What is this error? And why is this error shown to me? Maybe am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Sorry for mistake, if any.

Comment: check this `UPPDATE` clause.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry i made a mistake when i had written part of word after paste.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: 4.7.4. The latest version from site. I tried to install earlier versions, the error was there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run on your server:

`# dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Comment: I wasn't install phpmyadmin. I downloaded it from official site and unpack. I tried redownload and unpack it again. The error remained.

Comment: any other information is provided in message @KirillK. ? Just this code is returned?

Comment: Yeap. But the error doesn't appear today, when I have tried to make a screenshot. It's okay for now. But will it appear again? It's very strange.